# Aborting method call flow between DLLs in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I’m ´working on a WCF Service which basically encapsulates CSOM functionalities for SharePoint maintenance.

I deployed the Service to our IIS and noticed a strange behavior. What I noticed is this;

I have normal class structures where a method from dll A creates and uses classes from ddl B -> Nothing special, everything works fine in debug.

But deployed to our IIS the method call flow suddenly aborts on a certain point (between dlls). The log messages from nlog just stop without any error and the browser only shows a basic error page. ISS Logging does not show any information as well.

It seems that not a single method call can be made in the "next" class / method.

```
public DataFactoryClient(string webFullUrl)
 {
        // THIS LOG MESSAGE CAN BE FOUND IN LOG FILE
        Log.Trace("DataFactoryClient:DataFactoryClient(webFullUrl " + webFullUrl + ")");

        InformationProvider test = new InformationProvider();
```

.. Next class is part of another .dll

```
public class InformationProvider : IInformationProvider
{

   ....

    public RoomInformationProvider(string ctorWebFullUrl = "****")
    {
        // THIS LOG MESSAGE CAN NOT BE FOUND IN LOG FILE
        Log.Trace("InformationProvider:InformationProvider(ctorWebFullUrl " + ctorWebFullUrl + ")");
        ...
    }
```

Do I miss something ? Hope that you can help me out here ;-)

Greetz and thanks in forcast
Iki

Comment: 1) Make sure the DLL is correctly deployed. 2) Turn on includeExceptionDetailsInFaults in web.config, maybe you'll see more details in the error page. 3) Wrap the constructor call in try/catch and log any exception you might get server-side.

Comment: Thanks for that hint ! It helped ;-) The Problem was that the SharePointClient.dll were not packed to the deployment package. Actually I do not know why ..I thought by adding the reference to the dll project they would be deployed as a standard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nodots mentioned the check that all dlls are realy provided in the deployment package helped. SharePointClient and Runtime was not added to the folder.

The activation of includeExceptionDetailsInFaults showed the right error message